Trying to get an image next to flex containers on page
       <div class="second-part">
            <h2>This website is awesome</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nam, aut natus? Voluptate vel delectus ipsum unde maxime facere aliquid reiciendis quia est enim ducimus magni deleniti repudiandae eveniet, cumque quis.</p>
            <div>
                <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-img">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6194848/pexels-photo-6194848.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400" alt="brittany spaniel in forest looking at the sky">
            
        </div>
.second-part {
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 40%;

I have the image in a separate div than the items in flex and I figured the image would go on the remaining space to the right of the page. I'm not sure if this is a container issue, but I'd love an explanation for why the image the way it is isn't filling up the right of the page.

Use display: flex; on parent element of .second-part and .right-img.

The two div elements, second-part and right-image, are block level elements.
If you want to keep the same HTML stucture without adding an overall containing block, one way of getting them side by side is to make second-part float.


.second-part {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  align-items: left;
  margin-left: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 40%;
  background-color: pink;
}
<div class="second-part">
  <h2>This website is awesome</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nam, aut natus? Voluptate vel delectus ipsum unde maxime facere aliquid reiciendis quia est enim ducimus magni deleniti repudiandae eveniet, cumque quis.</p>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-image">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6194848/pexels-photo-6194848.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=400" alt="brittany spaniel in forest looking at the sky">
</div>




Don't use float if you use flex layout.

@DavidWeber I realise float is not 'normally' used nowadays for layouts other than when one really does want to float an item - in this case it does do the job so it would be good to know why it it not permissable in this particular circumstance - the float relates to that whole element, the flex relates to its children.

Using float along with flex layout can lead to unexpected behavior and conflicts, especially when you are trying to achieve responsive design. Flexbox and float are both layout techniques, but they serve different purposes.

Hi, yes, but I am not using float within the flex. What I am floating is that whole element. Do you have any reference for the problem you are highlighting - I can't find one.
